# Using divide and conquer

Tags: c, divide-and-conquer

So, I have a problem.

The input consists of two numbers `N` and `M`. `N` basically tells us the number of `1` that will be present and `M` is the number, with which we divide and return the remainder.

```
1≤N≤10^16
2≤M≤10^9

Sample input:
3 3
4 7
5 18

Sample output:
0
5   
5
```

Explanation:

```
111 % 3 = 0
1111 % 7 = 5
11111%18 = 5
```

Time constraints: Upto 1 sec.

Since the input is very large, I obviously cannot use the modulo operator. I was thinking of bitwise operators but that too will not let me be withing the time limit. Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: if you want an answer move this to code golf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay NetVipeC's answer got ugly really fast

This answer is based on three identities

```
x(1) = 1
x(n) = x(n-1) * 10 + 1
x(2n) = x(n)*(x(n)*9 + 2)
```

These hold over Z_M as well.

I wrote those identities bottom up, but the implementation is top down since its so much simpler.

```
#include <stdio.h>

long long modulo(long long n, long long m) {
    if (n == 1) return 1;
    long long mod = modulo(n / 2, m);
    long long whole = ((mod * 9 + 2) * mod) % m;
    if(n & 1)
        return (whole * 10 + 1) % m;
    return whole;
}

int main() {
    printf("%ld\n", modulo(3, 3));
    printf("%ld\n", modulo(4, 7));
    printf("%ld\n", modulo(5, 18));
    printf("%ld\n", modulo(1e6, 123456789));
    printf("%ld\n", modulo(1e15, 123456789));
}
```

Output:

```
time ./tst
0
5
5
1239742
93889873
./tst  0.00s user 0.00s system 56% cpu 0.002 total
```

Comment: that was great. However, like I am beginner to this, and I mean, how did you come up with that? How do you do that? This is really great. How can I learn to do that?

Comment: This one I just used the Feynman algorithm for. But the answer drew from discrete math and dynamic programming.

Answer (score 1):

I hope this is not Project Euler or other kind of site like that.

First the numbers `1111...` are named [`Repunit`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic).

As [modular arithmetic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic) state:

if `a1 = b1 mod n` and `a2 = b2 mod n` then:

```
a1 + a2 = b1 + b2 mod n
a1 - a2 = b1 - b2 mod n
a1 * a2 = b1 * b2 mod n
```

The Repunits of `size n` can be written in base 10 as: `1*10^n + 1*10^(n-1) ... + 1*10 + 1`.

This would be `1*10^n + 1*10^(n-1) ... + 1*10 + 1 = X mod n`

```
1 = x1 mod n
x1*10 + 1 = x2 mod n
x2*10 + 1 = x3 mod n
...
x(n-1)*10 + 1 = X mod n
```

The last modular result would be the solution:

Code in C++, updated code with Steve Cox propose:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <cmath>

long long repunit_module(long long repunit_size, long long n) {
    if (repunit_size < 100) {
        // Calculate normally
        long long module_value = 1;
        for (long long i = 2; i <= repunit_size; i++) {
            module_value = (module_value * 10 + 1) % n;
        }
        return module_value;
    } else {
        // x(2n) = (x(n+1) - x(n) + 1) * x(n)
        long long xn = repunit_module(repunit_size / 2, n); // x(n) mod n
        long long xn1 = (xn * 10 + 1) % n; // x(n+1) mod n
        long long rest = xn1 - xn + 1; 
        if (rest < 0) // normalyze for module
            rest += n;
        long long result = ((rest % n) * xn) % n;

        if (repunit_size % 2 == 1) { // if size is 2n + 1 calc the last
            return (result * 10 + 1) % n;
        } else { // if size is 
            return result;
        }
    }    
}

int main() {
    long long rps = std::pow(10, 16);
    std::cout << repunit_module(3, 3) << std::endl;
    std::cout << repunit_module(4, 7) << std::endl;
    std::cout << repunit_module(5, 18) << std::endl;
    std::cout << repunit_module(rps, 123456789) << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Heres a hint `x(2n) = (x(n+1) - x(n) + 1) * x(n)` that lets you skip ahead really quickly

Comment: or in the least readable way possible, note that `111111 = 111 * (1111 - 111 + 1)`